# Get images from query with relationship Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, querying

We need get images filename from query with relationship

Advertise model:

[image]

Advimages model:

[image]
Controller:

```
  $ads = Advertise::with('images')->take(3)->get();
```

view:

[image]
The error:

[image]

Comment: Please, post the code in your question, we don't deal with images here.

Answer (score 0):

your `$ads` variable is a collection.
you simply are using the wrong variable (as you are already iterating over your ads and are within that loop).
just use `$a` as it seems to be the variable holding your current Advertisement